# Creating a curved cutter to cut into a sphere - Making a Jack-o-lantern

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers

I want to create a jack-o-lantern with a mouth that stretches almost 90 degrees around the jack-o-lantern. My previous strategy was to create a SVG image, make it solid, and subtract it from the pumpkin.

What I'd like to do is curve the cutter so It wraps partway around the pumpkin. I don't know how to do that. I'd appreciate suggestions.

Comment: Not explained enough imo - send images, .blend or something Rben!

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50538/how-to-cut-an-object-along-a-curve/ and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66942/how-would-you-model-a-sphere-with-a-shell-like-object/ or https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/59219/how-do-i-turn-an-imported-svg-into-a-sphere/ also https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52904/wrap-curve-around-sphere/

Comment: Will attach blend if I figure out how. Picture a pumpkin model. Put a cylinder around it almost touching. Then take SVG image of desired cutout. Import the SVG image, turn it into a mesh, blow it up to the right size, rotate it 90 degrees around X. I'd like to have that curved like the cylinder and then shrink it inward to create the cutting shape that would be applied with a boolean operator.

Comment: I may have an answer. I'm going to try using a curve modifier on the cutting shape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I found the answer here: [What's the most elegant way to cut shapes out of a mesh](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46284/whats-the-most-elegant-way-to-cut-shapes-out-of-a-mesh). I created a bezier curve that covered the curve where I wanted to put the face cut, then I applied a curve modifier to the jack-o-lantern face mesh and moved it into position. Next I applied the boolean operator on the pumpkin using the face and the difference setting. That neatly cut the face out of the pumpkin, giving me the Jack-o-lantern I wanted. Well, almost. I messed up a couple of things (make sure your face is deep enough to cut far enough into the pumpkin) and have to go back and fix them, but the general purpose works.

I hope someone finds this helpful.